How can I diagnose and fix a non-functioning graphics card after physical damage?
4 months ago, I bought a brand new ASUS TUF Gaming GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER, but I damaged it while moving to a new house, and it no longer works. I would like to know the possible solutions to repair it.
Current Status of the Graphics Card
This is what it currently looks like:






It looks fine except for this part:

Although the shorter length of the 2nd-right pin is expected, the right-most pin is unexpectedly short, as you can see from this video.
What I Plan to Do
Since the right-most pin is too short, I am thinking of extending it myself by soldering. However, I am not sure if this is the correct approach. I am also inexperienced with soldering and could not find a good tutorial on YouTube.
What I Have Checked

The motherboard (Gigabyte Z390 Gaming X) was also damaged during the move, so I replaced it with a new one (Gigabyte Z390 UD), but I still get no display signal.
I tested another graphics card (MSI AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT) in the same PCIe slot, and Windows successfully launched without any issues.
I updated the BIOS to the latest version (F11), but it didn’t make a difference.
Although there is no display output, the OS still boots up, and I can access the PC via Remote Desktop from another machine. However, the OS does not recognize the graphics card.

Based on this, I am assuming the graphics card is damaged.
FWIW, the LED on the graphics card turns on, but the fan never spins:


I believe there's conductive ink pens, this might be the safest option, over soldering. Solder won't stick to 'bare' PCB from experience.  I'd post it an answer if I had direct experience but I've never tried this before.

It sounds like you think you damaged it, when really what happened is it "just stopped working". And since the card is only 4 months old, you should try returning it under the manufacturers guarantee or see if ASUS support would be willing to offer their expertise at no additional cost.

From the picture in the question and using PCIE (PCI Express) 1x, 4x, 8x, 16x bus pins and signals the damaged card-edge fingers on the edge connector are:

B81 PRSNT#2
B82 RSVD#2

RSVD#2 isn't used.
PRSNT#2 is to support hot-plug detect - see PCIe PRSNT# signal connection and PCIe Present pin working principle
As per PCIe Hardware Design Guide PRSNT#2 (and PRSNT#1) are supposed to be shorter than the other fingers so PRSNT#1 and PRSNT#2 are the last to make contact during a hot-plug. The length of the PRSNT#2 finger on the non-functioning graphics card in the question looks about the same length as on an undamaged PCIe card:

Therefore, the card probably has more damage that just that visible on the card edge.

In other words, those pins, are likely NOT the reason your card is not functional.

@JourneymanGeek @user705502 @Mastaxx @Chester @Ramhound
Thank you so much for your reply. Although the conductive ink pen was what I was looking for, it was unrelated, as Chester also mentioned. So, I contacted ASUS support. However, since the pins were damaged, they deemed it unrepairable, following "the service guideline that when we receive the product in a condition that is not as it was from the ASUS factory, caused by CID." In other words, ASUS never fix your device if the device has any visible damage, no matter wether it's related or not.
The result was disappointing, but it can't be helped. I really appreciate your help anyway.

This is the Outcome, not the answer. Chester gave you the answer. While it is ultimately up to you which post to mark as the answer, you should really select Chester's answer if you want to actually thank them for sharing their knowledge with you.

@music2myear I see. Thanks. Changed.
